# android - screen orientation vs home button onStop()

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-homebutton

I am trying to build an app where if the user press the home button , he goes back to a home page via an intent (  so via the `onStop()` button that is overridden ) 
but the problem happens when the orientation changes, usually it also calls the onStop method so I go back to the home page also.

I tried to read the boolean `isFinishing` but anw it is never true.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ... just posting the answer to let the other know 
in android there is a method called :  `isChangingConfigurations()` ..
if its true than the rotation happenned